# How to put hooks in the getter and setter methods

Tags: java, spring, java-8

I would like to build the following thing. If the title of the question is vague than please change it accordingly since i was not able to think of a better title.

Put some kind of hook in the getter and setter of my pojo. So when i call any reference attribute of my pojo i can make a database call and can get the latest of reference.

For example

```
Class A{
}

Class B{
  Class A a;

  @MagicAnnotation(type=getter)
  getA(){
    return a;
  }

  @MagicAnnotation(type=setter)
  setA(a){
    this.a=a;
  }

}
```

So whenever a getter or setter is annotated with @MagicAnnotation i know i need to do database operation. Like for getter i can get load the reference attribute again from database.

Is there any already existing tool which does this tasks ? or any leads how can i develop such a functionality ?

I am using spring. :)

Comment: Since you mention database accesses, have you considered using ORM frameworks, such as JPA? Having a database call on every getter and setter call seems to be a rather bad idea…

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard case for JEE interceptors (see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkigq.html) which are implemented in every CDI framework (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkhjx.html)

For getting started with such a framework in standalone code (ie. without setting up a server infrastructure) have a look at **weld-se** (http://weld.cdi-spec.org/)

Note, that - when you move to cdi - interceptors only work for manged beans, not for data objects which you create yourself. This might require some refactoring.

Comment: Hint: The question has a "Spring" tag.